# PHP equivalent to Objective-C's @"string"

Tags: php, objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I'm writing a class library for PHP which will implement some of the features of the Cocoa framework in Objective-C.

Objective-C has a handy shorthand for creating `NSString` objects :

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World!";
```

I'm trying to come up with the most elegant equivalent for this in PHP.
At the moment I've gone with:

```
$string = a("Hello World!");
```

`a()` is a function which creates the appropriate object.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant syntax ?
It obviously has to be valid PHP code.

Comment: I don't understand your question, `$a = "Hello";` already creates a string.

Comment: That's a standard PHP string. What I'm talking about is actually an object which represents a string, analogous to the NSString class in Cocoa. Have a quick look at http://pastebin.com/bippXMfd to see what the a() function does.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question. He has a custom class with more functionality and methods than a normal string, and is object oriented. Not that PHP is the best choice for object oriented programming, but the question makes perfect sense, and the concern for syntax is valid. I haven't used PHP too extensively, but I don't think there are any other ways to implement this, because that's basically the only way to implement a function.

Comment: By way of some background, I'm writing Cocoa apps on the Mac which talk to a web API on the server written in PHP. The common Cocoa objects (NSString, NSArray, etc) have nice functions for serialising themselves to XML and back again. I'm writing a matching class library in PHP for the server side which contains the same objects and methods (ok, not identical, but a PHP equivalent). It's on source forge if anyone's interested, but it's still in the very early stages.

Answer (score 2):

The proper idiom would be something along the lines of:

```
$string = new NSString("Hello, World!");
```

While you might be able to come up with something more terse, this is the best way. A few extra characters for zounds of clarity and following standard language conventions is worth it.

Edit:

Based on your comment, I would recommend creating an NS namespace, and adding any single-letter functions to that namespace, so you could do the following:

```
$string = ns\s("Hello, World!");
```

You could do the same for NSNumber, etc, without polluting the global namespace or breaking PHP idiom.

Comment: That's true enough, and the library I'm writing supports this. However that way of creating NSString objects is a little long handed, so Objective-C has a shorthand version - NSString *string = @"Hello, World!"; - which does exactly the same thing and comes in pretty handy, so I'm trying to come up with some PHP syntax which approximates it. On the aspect of standards, this syntax is considered standard in Objective-C and as that's what I'm mimicking, it would be nice to, err, mimic it. :-)

Comment: The namespace idea is intriguing. I'll have a think about that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Core Foundation, Apple use `CFSTR("constant string");`, so there's precedent for that kind of approach…